Encrypting algorithm doesn't give all the output
I'm currently trying to write an encrypting algorithm as:
TXT the sequence of characters to be encrypted
ENC the output sequence (at the beginning, ENC is empty)
i) I take C, the first character of TXT, and add it to the end of ENC.
ii) let X be the ASCII code of C modulo 8 (e.g. for the letter 'b', its ASCII code is 98, so X = 2)
iii) I take the first X characters of TXT and move them to the end of TXT (if there are at least X characters left in TXT)
iv) repeat until TXT is empty
at the end, ENC will contain the encrypted message.
envoyer, envoyer_recevoir are just some functions to communicate with the server. The message i'm trying to crypte is:

Chere Alice,
Nous devons etre plus prudents, il faut anticiper avant que nous ne soyons
reperes. J'ai termine dans l'urgence mon nouveau schema de chiffrement que j'ai
appele 'crypteMove'.
Durant l'encryption, nous allons modifier l'ordre des lettres du texte selon
des regles bien etablies. Voici le principe :
soit TXT la sequence des caracteres a encrypter
soit ENC la sequence de sortie
(au debut, ENC est vide)
j'effectue ensuite la manipulation suivante:
i) je prends C le premier caractere de TXT et le rajoute a la fin de ENC
ii) soit X le code ASCII de C modulo 8 (par exemple pour la lettre 'b', son
code ASCII est 98 donc X = 2)
iii) je prends les X premiers caracteres de TXT et les deplace a la fin de TXT
(s'il reste au moins X caracteres dans TXT)
iv) je recommence jusqu'a ce que TXT soit vide
a la fin, ENC contiendra le message encrypte.
Je te donne un exemple sur le message suivant :
"Petit message court."
Devient :
"Pee ct mosusriae.ttg"
Je sais que tu es l'une des rares personnes a pouvoir mettre en oeuvre une
technique complexe comme celle-ci, cela devrait mieux nous proteger que le code
de cesar que nous utilisions jusqu'a present. Cependant, pour me montrer que tu
as bien compris ma methode, il faut dans un premier temps que tu me renvoies ce
message complet crypte comme je viens de te l'expliquer.
Bien a toi,
Bob.
PS: Pour t'aider, voici la trace d'execution sur "Petit message court."
TXT:Petit message court.
ENC: <vide>
C = P
TXT:etit message court.
ENC:P
C = e
TXT:essage court.tit m
ENC:Pe
C = e
TXT: court.tit mssage
ENC:Pee
C =
TXT:court.tit mssage
ENC:Pee
C = c
TXT:t.tit mssageour
ENC:Pee c
C = t
TXT: mssageour.tit
ENC:Pee ct
C =
TXT:mssageour.tit
ENC:Pee ct
C = m
TXT:our.titssage
ENC:Pee ct m
C = o
TXT:sageur.tits
ENC:Pee ct mo
C = s
TXT:ur.titsage
ENC:Pee ct mos
C = u
TXT:sager.tit
ENC:Pee ct mosu
C = s
TXT:r.titage
ENC:Pee ct mosus
C = r
TXT:itage.t
ENC:Pee ct mosusr
C = i
TXT:age.tt
ENC:Pee ct mosusri
C = a
TXT:e.ttg
ENC:Pee ct mosusria
C = e
TXT:.ttg
ENC:Pee ct mosusriae
C = .
TXT:ttg
ENC:Pee ct mosusriae.
C = t
TXT:tg
ENC:Pee ct mosusriae.t
C = t
TXT:g
ENC:Pee ct mosusriae.tt
C = g
TXT: <vide>
ENC:Pee ct mosusriae.ttg

As output i get:

Ceeuo plrei ftenn sneJitn leoa smcf qe
pertertno almerelet snrlinisoprc : s Taseeat aet s E seei
(a d, ed jf eeaiunnedlecceXTljtlnCo c ACdm 8 (pa ee lt'
c ACe dX = edsprircceTt dc lnT (s rt mX ccesTem jq'es valncin meytJtneelseat     "te cte :     "eo.Js qesusr peeoeev
cqelceec di mnouc
crusiiinue Cnpoou
bni mhofnrireumves clrtm ve'ein,.Podvat dcoPee ctTee ctCv =XTts ctCCe:s ct mPee:o m
Ce
XTrtsePe=XTi moPe =XTsoEe =XTaei
CeCm:risePemoaetCeo
Ttgem=XTe
CeosXTiaePemCrTtt:eo=XT.:eo =XTtCeoCe:tCeo
=XT
Ceo.
XTEeo.tTNco. g<>emiehecNnunuc aa qen
pr.mncnudfualye
a lytnsii l dtdt
see.lieXTqncecetaqnob Evee lpl saejrseete eefNteIeumut'otn  jrs X ere XTeeid
'uaaen  jecuq Tiie f ola e.dupl eg:Pesoincsie
asunasnumn unpem-laiu prgeeeu jqaprnat mr q ti cr m i at ue q tromope jetxpl. touiroaetutae
TtaeEd P
:imoP
XTei
C =Ttse
=osE
c:tg:ct mri
c
:srte =TtEcC
XTri
c
=:.E cs uariEcs =rtCcs =:ges
i
aeCcsiC
eN ma =TEcsie
t: csietgcsie
X:E tse=:iePesat Ai
svsdlnuers ea' neiejieoe,ldde eds t Vip
i lereproc s  useeunv peprrrr Truid   s lI Clplalbs d sopeerdlaa f ieisrd)  rmacXT
a,nec
enuasnmr
e trt i t'rno  oeocceetq ldqnotdrmumd dpeses
aecode
aiB
t iile stsr
PtsrN
Tsu:
suNTrisN
ci m:CTsrN
:gPemt c
XoN
ste suee
tCT
:t
ieP cuT
PesaT
Pes
X.es  .NsC
tPes
=:eit
XTEtrgdtutpr o ei dne hrn'ui orr txeebiie e arnCuet-naiu  n ae a aa eXoo eo9c) nate aeso TeedErepee se
tet m"u dsapveec o avs esose,nssenei cgcis l
o'cuim"im
<
e
=rt
ctPeu
e.E
auts.
u
eTst
rsC ot m:gsTNCgm:gr
gmTPea =C m
ea
vcsr
e pt aitysae maea c'nf ug  ndr-eu)'am
Ci d   ESdpo e  2la el l r a
n otsr o m is.e
ersrte mlr oe t' ueatst em mee r,' s.u>rNt
TaNt
st
o
t:  =NXiaNT:ut oEr:Er
EuNr
g T tCP m TCo sev 'ueMcsolbltc
lt if t    m
dr r ,I8
ms Tnu-enei auPu  louulxudusereupus yeuPS  rirgotE.tCt
sCeCETCg Ttg
Na
mN.iT t:t
Ngd uoiseemvueecc yNNiooeI eease iN
xmgt ern ee  l.e, mpeirbe"X:gaeog
etgstP m
see.t
:t:umusC:teuuh t.neesd
uae os p Xest sru setieese apen  q
c oeeCECe
Ng
CP
.C
t c
at:rT
.,o 'o  esrCttxrnt ueDeeieautmee:CT
a:gCPt:Et u tt CraCNsoppD 'octe scCnaettse e
ne::t.au
s sEu, rgo i e i eXovirm pneug.uCN u
r
rscpsau:S  d"g ot s.aC: .Xt u  ao-     as   hx,lB.u .
lrov  nETEr'ga igP  tni
oNrteutsxatt rTsXtte:v
Current ENC Len 2247
Current Txt Len  0

And server says that i make a mistake on 2245th character and "vs tteaPv:" is missing. I used address sanitizer and also add some checkpoints but i couldn't get anything.
 #include "client.h"
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>


 char TXT[MAXREP];//MAXREP is given by server and =100000
 char ENC[MAXREP];
 char C;
 int lenENC_courant=0;

 void delete(char txt[],int x){
     int len= strlen(txt);
     if (x >= len) {
         txt[0] = '\0';
         return;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < len - x; i++) {
         txt[i] = txt[i + x];
     }
     if(len -x>0){
         txt[len - x] = '\0';
     }
 }

 void add(char txt[], int x, int lentxt){
     if (lentxt + x >= MAXREP) {
         printf("Error: Buffer overflow risk, cannot add characters\n");
         return;
     }
     for (int i = 0; i < x && i<lentxt; i++) {
         if(lentxt +i<MAXREP){
         txt[lentxt + i] = txt[i];
         }
     }
     txt[lentxt + x] = '\0';
 }
 
 void encrypte(char txt[]){
     if(strlen(txt)==0){
         return;
     }

     int x = (int) txt[0] % 8;
     C= txt[0];

     if(lenENC_courant <=MAXREP-1){
         ENC[lenENC_courant++]=C;
         ENC[lenENC_courant] = '\0';
     }
     if (lenENC_courant >= MAXREP - 1) {
         printf("Error: Buffer overflow risk in 'ENC' array\n");
         ENC[MAXREP - 1] = '\0';  
         return;
     }
    
     if(x==0){
         delete(txt,1);
       
     }
     else{
         delete(txt,1);
         int lentxt = strlen(txt);
         if(lentxt+x<= MAXREP){
             add(txt,x,lentxt);
         } 
         delete(txt,x);
     }
 }


 int main() {
     char reponse[MAXREP] = "Petit message court."; 
     connexion("**********");
     mode_debug(true);
     envoyer("login ******* *******");
     envoyer("load crypteMove");
     envoyer_recevoir("help",reponse);
     if(reponse==NULL){
         printf("On n'a pas pu prendre le reponse");
         return -1;
     }
     envoyer("start");

    
     while(strlen(reponse)>0){
         encrypte(reponse);
     } 
     envoyer(ENC);
     printf("\nCurrent ENC Len %d \n",lenENC_courant);
     int len_txt = strlen(TXT);
     printf("Current Txt Len  %d\n",len_txt);

     return 0;
 }


This would be a good time to learn to use a debugger. Step through the program and notice when the result is different from what you expect.

Where is vs tteaPv: supposed to come from?

For starters, what is MAXREP? Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger to make sure all lengths don't result in nul-terminating an input short of the end? Have a look at How to debug small programs

@Barmar vs tteaPv: should be ending in case of encrypting all the elements.

Do yourself a favor and try it with much shorter input first, like a single word or two. Once that works you can expand the sample.

@500-InternalServerError i already tried it with a test case as "Petit message court." like the exemple and it worked but whenever i tried with this input i get an error on 2245th character

In just a cursory look, I suspect where you are comparing lengths and then nul-terminating is causing the problem when an input exceeds what you expect resulting in an input being nul-terminated early. Look at all your = '\0' lines (could be = 0), and make sure you don't have a problem there.

Is 2245 at the end of the input (or close to it)? Check "off-by-one" ("off-by-a-few") errors. Also step iii) means "no change if there are less than X characters" or "move less than X characters to the end"?

envoyer("login ........ ......"); appears to be your credentials to im2ag-appolab.u-ga.fr. You may want to delete/hide them.

Or remove that code completely as it isn't something that is part of your example.

@pmg There is 2249 char. No change if there are less than X characters

Your code does not seem to work correctly with test message Petit message court. It returns Pee ct mosusriaetg instead of Pee ct mosusriae.ttg. It seems that the requirement is to copy whatever left in txt to ENC when x >= lentxt (in the example above .ttg is just copied to ENC). However the code continues add(txt, 5, 4) resulting in .ttg.ttg and then delete(txt, 5) resulting in ttg and so on.

This is a nice problem, and after some tinkering, I realized that you can perform the encryption in place, like this:
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void encrypt(char* txt)
{
    size_t len = strlen(txt);
    size_t start = 0;
    while (len > 0) {
        size_t c = *txt++;
        size_t x = c % 8;
        --len;
        if (0 < x && x < len) {
            char buffer[7];
            memmove(buffer, txt, x);
            memmove(txt, txt + x, len - x);
            memmove(txt + (len - x), buffer, x);
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char message[] = "Petit message court.";
    printf("TXT: \n----------\n%s\n----------\n", message);
    char *enc = _strdup(message);
    encrypt(enc);
    printf("ENC2: \n----------\n%s\n----------\n", enc);
    free(enc);
    return 0;
}

The moment you select the first character and move it to the new string you need one more character in the ENC string and one less in TXT. So you can simply use the beginning of TXT as the ENC string.
The next step is rotating the first x characters to the end of TXT. There are some fancy algorithms for this, but the fastest one (to my knowledge) is using an additional buffer. In this case we know that the maximum number of characters to rotate is 7, so a small buffer can do the job.
